# Calculating higher homotopy groups of (complements of) knots

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, knot-theory, higher-homotopy-groups

There are techniques to calculate the group of a knot, i.e. the fundamental group of its complement in a manifold, but are there techniques to calculate its higher homotopy groups?

Can anyone suggest a reference on this topic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In

```
MR0090053 (19,761a) Reviewed
Papakyriakopoulos, C. D.
On Dehn's lemma and the asphericity of knots.
Ann. of Math. (2) 66 (1957), 1–26.
55.0XMore links
```

It is proven that knot completements in $S^3$ are aspherical (all higher homotopy groups vanish)